# how do I calculate t.-statistic value and find two-sided P value using R?

Tags: r, statistics

Below is my dataset

```
dput(ex0112)
```

Dataset:

```
structure(list(BP = c(8L, 12L, 10L, 14L, 2L, 0L, 0L, -6L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, -3L, -4L, 2L), Diet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FishOil", "RegularOil"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

To find the t-statistic for entire (column BP) I have achieved it using the below R code.

```
library(Sleuth3)
t.test(BP~Diet, data=ex0112)
```

But how do I calculate For the hypothesis that mu is zero and construct the t -statistic for (column BP) for only **Regular Oil Diet** and also how to Find the two-sided p-value as the proportion of values from a t-distribution farther from 0 than this value using R?

Comment: Please don't post images of your data. We can't copy and paste them into R to try things. Images also aren't searchable and mess with screen readers. Use `dput(ex0112)` and paste that into your question.

Comment: Thank you so much @BenNorris
I have updated my question.
I am new to this programming world. I am still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. You can use one variable in `t.test()` which has the options for `mu` parameter and the `two-sided` alternative you want. Here the code using your `dput()` data as `df`:

```
#Test
test <- t.test(df$BP[df$Diet=='RegularOil'], mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")
test
#Extract p-value
test$p.value
```

Output:

```
One Sample t-test

data:  df$BP[df$Diet == "RegularOil"]
t = -0.94943, df = 6, p-value = 0.3791
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.088292  1.802578
sample estimates:
mean of x 
-1.142857
```

And p-val:

```
[1] 0.3790617
```